# Android: Here map, how to load tile image async?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, here-api

As the tile, i'm using [Here-map](https://here.com/).

I'm trying to custom raster tiles from S3 server instead. Folow the documentation, there are two class that support me to do that: UrlMapRasterTileSourceBase and MapRasterTileSource.

In my case, i tried to new an instance of MapRasterTileSource then override getTileWithError(int x, int y, int zoomLevel) function to load my tile image from S3 server.

The problem is the time to load an image is too long, and the UI seem be lagged.

In the document, here is part:

> Note: Ensure that getTileWithError() returns within a reasonable
>   amount of time. If your operation takes a longer period of time,
>   launch an asynchronous operation and return the
>   TileResult.Error.NOT_READY error code while the operation is in
>   progress.

But, i don't have any idea how to apply that. I have tried to load image with a callback, but don't know what to do after having result.

Could you give me a hand on this please!?

Answer (score 1):

How are you loading raster tiles from S3? Is it a synchronous HTTP request that you call from getTileWithError?

The proper flow should be:
-getTileWithError() // for a particular x, y, z
-Execute the tile fetch from your S3 layer asynchronously via a thread or AsyncTask.
-Meanwhile, getTileWithError() will be called continously, and you can return "TileResult.NOT_READY"
-When the image is fully downloaded, then return the image back to the runtime.

If the amount of time spent in the getTileWithError takes too long, the tile source will be disabled automatically.

Comment: -When the image is fully downloaded, then return the image back to the runtime. => So it means that we have to cache the result, right? At this time, i do the same with what you suggest by load async, return NOT_READY, and when data ready in callback -> save it to cache file, the next time when getTileWithError() call again i check if there is cache file for that tile then load. Or do you have other solution for "return the image back to the runtime"?